# please help me in solving this count query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to find the count of mobile nos from a table like the below query

```
select name, count(mobile no) as count from table where count<=5
```

This query throws me error...please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server, if you have object names that contains spaces or other special characters, you need to put the names in square brackets.

Furthermore, if you want to apply a filter to an aggregate function, this should happen in the `HAVING` part of the statement, instead of in the `WHERE` part. This also means that you need to GROUP BY the name column.

Try to change your query to this:

```
select name, count([mobile no]) as count 
from table 
group by name 
having count([mobile no])<=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`select name, count([mobile no]) as count from table group by name having count([mobile no])<=5`

Answer (score 0):

try Like This

```
select name, count([mobile no]) as count from table having count([mobile no])<=5
```

Comment: This will not work, as it is not possible to apply a WHERE filter to an aggregated column.

Comment: You will also need to GROUP BY the name column, or you will get an error that name is not part of an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you trying to do

```
select name from table having count(`mobile no`) <= 5
```